# Haskell coding issue

Tags: haskell

```
type Matrix = [[Rational]]

type Vector = [Rational]

data Network = Layer | None

type Layer = (Matrix,Vector,Network)

createNetwork :: [Matrix] -> [Vector] -> Network
createNetwork [] _ = None
createNetwork (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x,y,(createNetwork xs ys))
```

I dont understand why does this code returns the following error, since a layer is exactly fitting for a Network. It doesn't compile even if i define Network as 
Matrix Vector Network | None

This is the error :

```
neuro.lhs:17:33: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Network'
                  with actual type `(Matrix, Vector, Network)'
    * In the expression: (x, y, (createNetwork xs ys))
      In an equation for `createNetwork':
          createNetwork (x : xs) (y : ys) = (x, y, (createNetwork xs ys))
   |
17 | > createNetwork (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x,y,(createNetwork xs ys))
   |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've defined `Layer` twice, as two different things:

- As a *data constructor* (in `data Network = Layer | None`)
- As a *type alias* (in `type Layer = (Matrix,Vector,Network)`)

Those are not the same.

In the second line in `createNetwork`, you return a triad (a 3-tuple). While it's equivalent to the type alias `Layer`, it's not a `Network`.

You should probably change your type definitions to something like this:

```
data Network = L Layer | None

type Layer = (Matrix,Vector,Network)
```

Then you should be able to write something like:

```
createNetwork :: [Matrix] -> [Vector] -> Network
createNetwork [] _ = None
createNetwork (x:xs) (y:ys) = L (x,y,(createNetwork xs ys))
```

I'm not nearby a Haskell compiler right now, so I can't check, but let me know if that doesn't work, and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Thank you, its working fine. I am sorry for getting stuck on this :P